# How to use react route on heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple web app, that is created by create-react-app.

All of page make with react route work be fine in local.

```
class App extends React.Component{


    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Menu/>
                    <div className="page-content">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Hello}/>
                    <Route exact path="/signup" component={Register}/>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is sever code:

```
// setting application
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

and

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
  })
```

But when i deploy on heroku, it didn't work. When i click the links, it display Cannot GET /signup.

Comment: You need to make sure all your routes serve the `index.html` file, and not just the `/` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08).

What is the problem that you have, is that when you click on link, server tries to find resource on full path. That resource doesn't exist.

So what is solution? For every request to frontend you need to return index.html and leave to react router to do the routing.

In tutorial that is setup with this code:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

You should modify you code to look like this:

```
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
  })
```